# Multidimensional array JSON returning Object Object

Tags: arrays, json, multidimensional-array

My JSON is here ... I want to have only CITIES - not the rest of it, only city names inside on option values which I want then to insert into form.
But my script is returning all of it. Am I missing something ?

Code here:

```
<script>
            $(function () {
           var shops =  new Array();
           var show_options = '';
           $.getJSON('shops.json', function(data) {
               for (var i = 0; i < data.cities.length; i++) {
                console.log('<option value="'+data.cities[i]+'>'+data.cities[i]+'</option>');
                   }

           });

        });
</script>
```

JSON FILE I AM IMPORTING

```
{       "cities":
            [{
                    "Bratislava":
                        [
                        {
                        "address": "– Supermarket KON-RAD - Cesta na Senec 24"
                        },
                        {
                        "address": "– ASTÉVIA - Predajňa zdravej výživy (OC CENTRAL) - Metodova 6"
                        },
                        {
                        "address": "– Paleo Dobre Dobroty –OC Fresh Market - Rožňavská 1"
                        },
                        {
                        "address": "– Bioobchod Slnečnica, - www.slnecnica.sk - Kvačalova 49"
                        },
                        {
                        "address": "– YEME – plnochutné potraviny - Tomášikova 46/A"
                        }
                        ],
                    "Banská Bystrica":
                        [
                        {
                        "address": "– Predajňa racionálnej výživy TT RACIO - www.ttracio.sk - Spojová 19"
                        },
                        {
                        "address": "– London tea&Natura Shop - www.londontea.sk - Horná 32"
                        }
                        ]
            }]
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that data.cities is an array with one object, whose keys are city names, so you need to iterate over these keys:

```
$.getJSON('shops.json', function(data) {
  Object.keys(data.cities[0]).forEach(function (city) {
    console.log('<option value="' + city + '">' + city + '</option>');
  });
});
```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/oQ6QAhyJCpvNNlQNtJu6?p=preview

Comment: Fast as light!, salute to you my friend :) thanks a lot.